# How to set up FK's between different classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a few classes for an application I am trying to write. The relationship goes like this:
A User can have many To Do Lists,
A To Do List can have many To Do Items.
Here's the code:

```
public class ToDo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public bool? InProgress { get; set; }
    public bool? IsComplete { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public ToDoList? ToDoList { get; set; } 
    public Guid? ToDoListId{ get; set; }
}

public class ToDoList
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public List<ToDo>? ToDos { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; } // Be sure to properly hash and salt passwords
    public string? ProfilePhotoUrl { get; set; } 
    public List<ToDoList>? ToDoLists { get; set; } 
}
```

My reasoning is:

A To Do Item needs a link back to the To Do List item it is part of, however it can be created outside of a To Do List so it is a nullable property.

A To Do List needs a relationship with its User and cannot exist without a User so it is not nullable here.

However, I'm not sure whether a User profile needs a link to the To Do List as it is already referenced in the To Do List.

Comment: Why do you need `ToDoListId` reference in `ToDo`? The adding/removing/processing will be a job of the `ToDoList` it has everything. I've also concerns with `ToDoLists` in `User`, you can query all todolists to find all belonging to the user.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I'm not sure whether a User profile needs a link to the To Do List as it is already referenced in the To Do List.

It is not necessary for the `User` to have a collection property for `ToDoLists`, it is assumed by *convention* because `ToDoList` has a `User` reference.

- For 1:N relationships we only need to define *one* of the endpoints. The other, if no match is found will be assumed. If you only specify the *many* end of the relationship and a FK property cannot be identified in the dependant entity then a shadow property will be created in the database model for you.

Including it can have some interesting implications. Adding this collection property will allow you to efficiently write expressions and filter criteria on `IQueryable<User>` expressions that need to evaluate or include some or all of the related `ToDoList` items.
But this convenience comes at a cost, when EF change tracking is enabled and `ToDoList` items are loaded into a change tracking context that also has `User` items, then EF will attempt to connect the two types of entities together. Apart from the CPU hit, this can lead to issues when you try to edit, delete or view items through `User.ToDoLists` that has only been partially loaded from the database.

- this doesn't happen very often, but with concepts like `User` vs `Task` where there are generally so many `Task` type items that they will almost always be filtered to a sub-set of active records, bulk operations or methods like `User.ToDoLists.Find()` can return unexpected results if they operate only on the records already loaded in memory while other records remain in the database.

If you are not going to use `User.ToDoLists...` in any LINQ-to-Entity queries, or not really going to use this property at all in your code base, it would be best practise to leave it out of the Model.

For collection properties like this it is often better to leave it out at first and add the property back if you find a need for it. Especially in the `User` type entities, where the `User` is likely to be referenced in many different entities but we never need to traverse back from the `User` to the entities that it is referenced in.

- Use explicit lookup queries if you want to support deleting the user and deleting all reference data related to them. Cascade Delete rules will work for this but `User` is usually so tightly bound into your schema that the wrong cascade delete rule could end up deleting a lot, or all of the data altogether.

Answer (score -1):

According to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many), `public List<ToDoList>? ToDoLists { get; set; }` not required:

> A one-to-many relationship is made up from:
>
> - One or more primary or alternate key properties on the principal entity; that is the "one" end of the relationship. For example, Blog.Id.
> - One or more foreign key properties on the dependent entity; that is the "many" end of the relationship. For example, Post.BlogId.
> - Optionally, a collection navigation on the principal entity referencing the dependent entities. For example, Blog.Posts.
> - Optionally, a reference navigation on the dependent entity referencing the principal entity. For example, Post.Blog.

The code in official documentation is this:

```
// Principal (parent)
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>(); // Collection navigation containing dependents
}

// Dependent (child)
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; } // Required foreign key property
    public Blog Blog { get; set; } = null!; // Required reference navigation to principal
}
```

**Note:** Do not let the `// Required reference navigation to principal` comment confuse you - it doesn't mean that the reference navigation property is required, but that the relationship is required. Otherwise it would be a nullable reference type, as you can see in the [Optional one-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many#optional-one-to-many) paragraph.

So, in your code - mind the comments:

```
public class ToDo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public bool? InProgress { get; set; }
    public bool? IsComplete { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public ToDoList? ToDoList { get; set; }  // Optional
    public Guid? ToDoListId{ get; set; } // Required
}

public class ToDoList
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // Required
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public List<ToDo>? ToDos { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; } // Required
    public User User { get; set; } // Optional
}

public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // Required
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; } // Be sure to properly hash and salt passwords
    public string? ProfilePhotoUrl { get; set; } 
    public List<ToDoList>? ToDoLists { get; set; } // Optional
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the documentation - hadnt come across it yet. Made the changes (took out the optional lines) and it didnt make a difference to the tables so seems like what I had before was the same thing. I guess EF is automatically making the connections without me explicitly coding it.

Comment: Did you expect the database to look different? If you kept the required properties and removed the optional ones, the database should still look the same